# SQLAlchemy / MySQL Search Algorithms

Tags: mysql, search, sqlalchemy

I have a Pylons app running on SQLAlchemy over MySQL. I have a data model with over 26,000 entries. These entries have titles (Unicode(256) columns) and I would like to be able to search for a title (with performance in mind). I want the search for a title in the 'smartest' way possible - for example I would like to be able to find 'Banks' based on the search term 'BBank', and so forth. Are FULLTEXTs what I am looking for? Is there some other sort of algorithm I can implement?

Thanks!